# Is there a way to run the Balanced Brawl mod from my standard Homebrew Channel GECKO install?

Tags: mods, nintendo-wii, super-smash-bros-brawl

The [Balanced Brawl download page](http://balancedbrawl.net/downloads-instructions/) provides a download that you have to load on a blank SD card.  Once you load the game, you enter the Stage Builder option and it runs an exploit, starting the GECKO homebrew program, which then loads the mod.

The SD card I have for my Wii already has the [Homebrew Channel](http://wiibrew.org/wiki/Homebrew_Channel), which I've loaded with several homebrew programs, including GECKO, that I don't want to delete.

Is there a way to get Balanced Brawl to load from an existing Homebrew Channel install without wiping out the rest of the contents from the SD card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember things correctly (I don't have access to my Wii + SD card at the moment), you can **just take the `DATA` and `private` folders from the download and stick them on your SD card**. Gecko should pick up the codes no matter how it's launched (the special SD-only method just uses an exploit to load Gecko from inside the game).

`DATA` contains the actual Gecko codes while `private` contains the replacement game files (characters, stages, etc.). You can merge the `private` folder with an existing one, if it's there, without any problem. Same with `DATA`.

Comment: This works! Accepted.  After copying the files you just have to load Gecko and launch the game.